# Conditional operation with += in C++

Tags: c++

What does these following statement do?
The output from gcc is:   1   101.
Can anyone explain why so is the case?

```
int a = 100, b = 108, c = 2;
a += b ? c = 1 : c = 0;
cout << c << " " << a;
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: That's the [ternary operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html).

Comment: its about precdence in c.   http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

Comment: @Rgarg: This is like asking to explain why 2+2 is 4. What exactly do you want to ask here? The output of your code immediately follows from simple basic rules of the language. Which specific basic rule gives you trouble?

Answer (score 5):

It's equivalent to:

```
a += (b ? (c=1) : (c=0));
```

Expanding out:

```
a = a + (b ? (c=1) : (c = 0));  // if (b!=0) then let c=1, else let c=0
```

Filling in for a and b:

```
a = 100 + (108 ? (c=1) : (c = 0));
```

Since `108` is not a "false" (0) expression, then the assignment of `c=1` is executed. A side effect of an assignment is that the assignment is equal to that assigned value.  And the result of that assignment is added to a:

```
a = 100 + (c=1);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
t = (c = 1); // t is 1
a = 100 + t;
```

And thus, since t is 1:

```
a = 100 + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add parenthesis (and space) so you can see what is happening:

```
int a = 100,b=108,c=2;

a += ((b != 0) ? c=1 : c=0);

cout<<c<<" "<<a;
```

Now replace with words (no longer legal C/C++):

```
int a = 100,b=108,c=2;

a += (if b != 0 then result=c=1 else result=c=0);

cout<<c<<" "<<a;
```

Then separate:

```
if b != 0 then result=c=1 else result=c=0
a += result
```

Since b != 0:

```
result = c = 1
a += result
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets expand

```
a = a + (b ? c = 1 : c = 0);
```

since `b = 108` which evaluates to `true`, the expression `c = 1` is evaluated.

Now, the assignment `c = 1` is successfull, so that returns `1`, and the expression becomes

```
a = a + 1
```

Therefore, in the end, the values are `c = 1` and `a = 101`

Answer (score 3):

```
int a = 100, b = 108, c = 2;
a += b ? c = 1 : c = 0;
```

this is equivalent to

```
a = a + (b ? c = 1 : c = 0);
```

This (?:) is ternary condition operator which work like `if-else` condition.
if condition is true it will run first otherwise second.

```
       (b ? c = 1 : c = 0;)
 if true    ^^^^^
 if false           ^^^^^^
```

as b=108 which will give TRUE, so it will make `c=1` and return c;
now
 `a = a + 1;`
this will make `a = 101`

Answer (score 2):

`?` is the ternary operator. It's logically equivalent to the following:

```
int a = 100,b=108,c=2;

if(b) {
  c = 1;
} else {
  c = 0;
}

a+=c;
// c is 1 because b is true (nonzero)
// a is a+c = 101
```

Comment: It's not equivalent. This produces different output.